# how to enable command line autocomplete after sqlite

Tags: linux, tabs, autocomplete, sqlite

Once upon a time when I started sqlite from the command line I could using the tabbing autocomplete to enter the database name. This has not worked for a while now. 
Any suggestions on how to do this? (Possibly specifically for files with a .db suffix.)

Comment: Are you using Bash (or zsh)? Do you have [bash-completion](http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/) installed and activated?

Comment: bash. bash-completion is enabled - just not working for sqlite.

Answer (score 3):

From: http://www.linux.com/archive/feed/54005

complete -G "*.db" sqlite would associate .db files with sqlite.

For permanent associations, you need to add the command to one of the bash startup scripts, such as ~/.bashrc.